# Ping spikes of ~2500ms constantly

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-vista, ping, lag

Starting today, I have been experiencing ping spikes while playing a few games. It happens on every game but only on this computer - my other computers which share the same router have no problems. I have run a ping test in command prompt:

```
Pinging www.l.google.com [173.194.66.104] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=54ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=44ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=42ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=41ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=52ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=57ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=2377ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=43ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=42ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=61ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=33ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=44ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=42ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=45ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=41ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=45ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=38ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=53ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=41ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=35ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=41ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=33ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=43ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=44ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=42ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=33ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=38ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=99ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=53ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=33ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=43ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=32ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=43ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=43ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=32ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=43ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=32ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=39ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=41ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=54ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=41ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=42ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=43ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=2632ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=40ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=56ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=32ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=36ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=40ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.194.66.104: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=47

Ping statistics for 173.194.66.104:
    Packets: Sent = 76, Received = 76, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 28ms, Maximum = 2632ms, Average = 103ms
```

My wireless card is very near new - I installed it about a week ago. The model is (according to windows device manager) is a Linksys WMP600N Wireless-N PCI Adapter with Dual-Band.

Computer specs:
Windows Vista Home Premium 32 bit
Intel Core Quad CPU @ 2.33 GHz
4.00 GB RAM

Hope someone can help

Comment: Instead of pinging Google try pinging your router address. Do you see the same spikes?  If not, then try pinging the next hop after that.  If it is happening for just your computer, perhaps you have some scheduled task that is saturating your network.

Comment: I get the same spikes when pinging my router address.

Comment: Maybe fire up `resmon` and watch the network tab?

Comment: Do the other computers also connect via WiFi?

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this problem appears to be to install and use Vista Anti-Lag, according to [this article](http://wlanbook.com/vista-wifi-60-second-lag-problem/). VAL 1.1.1 can be downloaded [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?jzx8b3lythxjakd).